# Need to upload .txt file to Azure Blob Storage from React Application

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have placed a file upload button in react. Upon triggered, it needs to connect to Azure Blob storage and the file should upload into Blob Storage.
I am not clear on connecting Azure Blob storage from React Application.
Need guidance on achieving this using react.

I have seen examples using Node and `.ts` notations but nothing using react.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by following https://stuarttottle.medium.com/upload-to-azure-blob-storage-with-react-34f37805fdfc and https://github.com/shubhamagarwal/Blob-Storage

Comment: this answer would be of no use to future readers , modify the answer and explain the steps you followed.Thanks